# Is there a convenient way of decorating the view options in several steps in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have some variables that will be used on every dynamic page, as it's used in the layout. Lets call them `user` and `cities`. For `user` I followed the express instruction to put a middleware infront of where I'd use it, except I did this:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
  req.user = { name: "Kit" };
  next();
});
```

It seem to make sense to put `user` on `req`, but it breaks down a bit on `cities` as it doesn't seem to semantically fit on the req object:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next){
  User.collection.distinct('city', function(err, response){
    req.cities = response;
    next();
  });
  req.menu = response;
});
```

Which I then follow by:

```
app.get('/:city', function(req, res){
  res.render('city', {  cities: cities, user: user });
});
```

Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything horribly wrong with how you're doing it, especially for a small code base.  It looks like the cities are tied to the user, so you might just want to hang the cities off of req.user by doing `req.user.cities = response` in your `User.collection.distinct` callback.  The other thing is that you are querying for these cities on every request.  This might be fine, but if that data is relatively static, using sessions and caching that data during the session lifetime would make sense as an optimization.

If you want to just have a clearer name, you can make a top level `locals` object, hang that off request, and then hang both user and cities off of that so `req.locals.cities`.

Comment: The cities is a list of all the cities for all users, but you are right about caching them. I figured since you have a way to set global view options through `app.set("view options" ... )` maybe I was overlooking something, but it seem like decorating `req.locals` is the way to go. Thanks. :)